# mvc MapRoute: How to generate a path with segments (slashes) and variables (passed after ?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to generate the following path 
**/products/tyres/all/all/all-all-Rall?page=2&ItemsPerPage=50**
What i do th solve this:

```
   routes.MapRoute("Tyres", "products/tyres/{ProducerId}/{SeasonId}/{Width}-{Height}-R{Diametr}",
        new { controller = "Products", action = "Tyres", ProducerId = "all", SeasonId = "all", Width = "all", Height = "all", Diametr = "all", page = UrlParameter.Optional, ItemsPerPage =  UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When i write `@Url.Action("Tyres","Products",  new { ProducerId = "5", Height="55" })`, route is correct **/products/tyres/5/all/all-55-Rall**

But when i add page parameter : `@Url.Action("Tyres","Products",  new { ProducerId = "5", Height="55", page=2 })`, the route is generated without segments : **/Products/Tyres?ProducerId=5&Height=55&page=10**

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try with defining additional route that can handle this particular request by defining all those extra params that you need? Also make sure that the extra params you need are separated by '/' instead of '-'.

Comment: I don't have problems with "-". Do u understand my problem? I need to generate a route which contains segments: /products/tyres...  AND parameters: page=2&ItemsPerPage=50. I don't know how to do this. Pease write concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, and if you want to see the url format as:

```
 /products/tyres/5/all/all-55-Rall?page=2&ItemsPerPage=6
```

, then try with the route template by excluding the Optional parameters from the template you posted:

```
        routes.MapRoute("Tyres", "products/tyres/{ProducerId}/{SeasonId}/{Width}-{Height}-R{Diametr}",
                               new
                               {
                                   controller = "products",
                                   action = "Tyres",
                                   ProducerId = "all",
                                   SeasonId = "all",
                                   Width = "all",
                                   Height = "all",
                                   Diametr = "all"
//Notice here, i have excluded the Optional URL parameters from your template: 
//page = UrlParameter.Optional, ItemsPerPage =  UrlParameter.Optional 
                               } 
                           );
```

With the optional parameters specified and if they are not supplied while calling, then the URL would be invalid:

```
/products/tyres/5/all/all-55-Rall//ItemsPerPage=6 //Notice here page value is not provided
```

, so it may be using querystring approach to handle this.

Hope this may help you.